# T-SQL aggregate function Logical error

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok I have a data table containing duplicate Reciept numbers and a
transaction value for each record, I need to simply list the total for
each unique Reciept number, this is obviously a simple problem but I
am missing something.

Any help is much appriciated

```
SELECT Gf_Receipt_number AS Reciept,
       SUM (Gf_Amount) AS Total
  FROM [TestP].[dbo].[Gf]
 WHERE Gf_Receipt_number IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY Gf_Amount
```

Would probably help to mention the the error I am recieving is:

Column 'TestP.dbo.Gf.Gf_Receipt_number' is invalid in the select list
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to group by Gf_Receipt_number instead of Gf_Amount

The GROUP BY clause indicates what columns are being used to distinguish one group of records from another whereas the column used in aggregate functions (such as SUM(Gf_Amount)) determine how the other columns within those records are combined into a single value.

Comment: Jesus when I said it was simple I wasn't joking!

I was looking for something more complicated than that, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably GROUP BY Gf_Receipt_number instead.

Answer (score 1):

You would want put GF_Receipt_number in your group by to get the error to go away.
[Group By Refrence](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)